# What does one do with a Ring of Power?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, the-one-ring, tolkiens-legendarium

I've looked over multiple different questions, and they either dealt with something similar, or gave frustratingly vague answers. So I'm certain that my question is not technically a duplicate (though by saying this I have likely doomed it to being labeled as one).

What are the 'powers' of the twenty Rings of Power? For one thing, the One made its wearer invisible and quasi - immortal. The Nine, I think, made their wearers invisible *only when they chose to be* when they were still human. But that's all I know about their powers.

I'm not asking about their corrupting influence, nor am I asking about what was done (for example; The Seven let the Dwarves build their wealth but made them greedy, I get that, but ***how did those rings increase the treasure troves***? Did they generate gold? Did they make the Dwarf Lords just that lucky when choosing mining spots?).

To reiterate my question, *what **powers** did the rings give their wearers*?

Comment: [Here's an answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33044/did-gandalf-wear-his-ring-of-power-throughout-the-trilogy/33048#33048) that says something about what Gandalf used his ring for. It doesn't cite the books though.

Comment: @Richard That just tells me that the rings helped  get them their wealth. It doesn't tell me how the rings managed this. They have the mountains of treasure because of the rings, but _how did the rings get that for them_?

Comment: @Anonymía - If you feel that the present question hasn't attracted the answers you want, the appropriate actions are to a) Post comments asking for additional info. Most users will be happy to oblige or b) Post a [bounty](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) explaining that the existing answers have insufficient info.

Comment: @Richard Alright then, and I appreciate your help: My uncertainty lies in the fact that the 'true power' of the rings are not known. By true power, I mean the defining attributes they give their bearers, which is described cryptically. For example, The Nine's true powers are not clear, but the bearers of The Nine were described as 'using' the rings to become grand kings and sorcerers, so The Nine clearly had some power besides invisibility if they could attain such stature for their bearers when used (did they give heightened charisma, or mind - control, or 'transported' them into kingship?).

Comment: And another thing; Galadriel apparently used her ring to 'create and sustain' Lothlorien. So did the ring 'conjure' up a city, or maybe levitated the stones to build it? Or did simply having the Ring of Water make her so intimidating that people just went ahead and built it for her? Also, Gandalf had the Ring of Fire, and described himself as a servant of the 'secret fire' and welding a 'flame of Anor' when he fought Durin's Bane, so did the ring enhance his Maiar power to the point where hue could slay such a demon?

Comment: The question @amaretto linked to seems to be the best target for a duplicate. See [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/46051/31394).

Comment: @randal'thor Again... phrases like 'Those who used the Nine Rings became mighty in their day, kings, sorcerers, and warriors of old. They obtained glory and great wealth, yet it turned to their undoing,' answer nothing that I've asked. Yeah the rings made them kings and wealthy, but _**how did they do it**_? Does putting on one of The Nine cause you to become a rich king when you open your eyes? I'm not certain that the answer is that simple.

Comment: My fundamental comment would be that it's not clear that the Rings had well-defined powers of the sort you seem to be imagining. I may be able to build that into an answer, but that's the summary of one.

Comment: @Anonymía - http://oakroadsystems.com/genl/ringfaq.htm

Comment: @DeerHunter That tells me that the general power of the rings is longevity, and that Sauron's influence partially shifts non-resiliant mortals into the spirit world. It (again vaguely) mentions enhancing the powers of the user, but to my knowledge, there were not 'powers' for Elves and the mortal races, so I'm not sure what that truly entails. Did Galadriel just have a knack for city-building that her ring amplified?

Comment: It mentions that The Seven got the Dwarves their wealth by amplifying bartering skill to the point where they easily got vast wealth through simple trade, which would explain how it 'takes gold to breed gold,' in the sense that the Dwarves had to give something in the 'deals,' or else they weren't using the rings 'dealmaking power'.

Comment: The power of the ring overtakes him/her, and he/her wont let anyone near it

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37077/discussion-on-question-by-anonymia-what-does-one-do-with-a-ring-of-power).

Comment: This is a legitimate question, I wish it wasn't closed. Although I'm not sure there is an answer in the text, this question is not asking a) what influence the Ring of Power has over its user, or other users, or b) what effect it has on others, but rather c) by what MEANS the bearer is able to use the inanimate ring to "shorten the distance between idea and effect" or however Tolkien put it. I don't think that question is answered elsewhere. Perhaps the question should be edited to make that clear.

Comment: The answer I would give is that the nature of magic in Tolkien's world actually prevents the Ring of Power from doing much more than enhancing the native abilities of its user. It may contain vast power, but the user has to have the native ability to do something magical (or merely exceptional) before the Ring can do anything to enhance that power.

Comment: This is because all magical abilities seem to stem from the angelic beings and their creations (the Ainur) who are the only characters actually able to "will" anything into being (and only the supreme being can give them life, although Sauron and other necromancers could trap existing spirits).

Comment: As one comment in the linked (but much broader) question noted, it's like the Japanese notion of Ki, or more accurately potential energy vs. kinetic energy (since it also seems to be subject to entropy -- once spiritual power is expended on making or breaking things, it's difficult to get back.) But it's all tied to the physical -- even the Silmarils and the Ring were dependent on some sort of "technology" relating to the inherent magical properties of Gold and Light, etc. (cf. *Morgoth's Ring*)